# Converting images into sprites

Tags: python, matlab

I'm trying to make a simple game on an FPGA board and I was hoping to use sprites for background and player characters. To do this I was told to use either Python or Matlab to take an image and convert it to a sprite. I am trying to convert the images to have 16 bits per pixel since the memory on the board can hold 16 bits per memory location.

For the past few days I've been searching for a tutorial or some sort of example to help me figure this out, but I've had no real luck. So I'm just hoping someone can give me advice on how to accomplish this or just point me in the right direction.

I don't know if this helps but I've discussed this with another person and the advice they gave me is to just take an image and put it into a matrix and divide it by 8. Then I'll have 15 bits for color, 5 each for RGB, and then a 16th bit for transparency. I should then write this matrix to a hex file and put it onto the boards memory. There is a program that properly edits the hex file into the correct format so that's not something I have to worry about.

Does this approach seem right? Or is there a better way? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I've never used FPGA so I could be off, but whats the difference between an image and a sprite?

Comment: You need to know exactly what format your display hardware is looking for.  There are a lot of ways to represent colors in 16-bits.  Figuring that out is the first problem.  If you do have 24-bit RGB color data and you want to map it to 15-bit RGB data you cannot simply divide by 8, you need to divide each of the three bytes in the RBG data by 8 and assemble them somehow.

Comment: Ok that was my initial thought. Like if I have 24-bit RGB data, then I would just take the top 5 bits for each channel and store it into my new array.

As for the format, I've been told that I need to store my edited data as a hex file, in a program like HexEdit for example, and that's all the board needs in order to store the sprite in memory.

I guess my question now is how can I edit the bits like you propose? I'm thinking it would be easier to use Matlab for this since it works very well with matrices, but is there something in Python that might be better suited for this particular task?

Comment: @TheLazyScripter I'm not too sure about the difference myself. From my understanding, if you want to use images to make a game of some sort sprites are preferred as they tend to take up less memory.

Beyond that I'm honestly not too sure about what makes something an image or a sprite. I haven't found a meaningful answer yet, but sprites just seems like one of those things that's loosely defined and people just use it when talking about a particular topic, in this case games. 

Maybe someone else has a better understanding/definition though, and I would very much like to hear it myself.

Comment: Typically a sprite is a pure data structure, and an image can be applied to it. This is what has me confused about your question. Converting larger/higher bit rate images can however be done as previously suggested. I assume you are asking about sprite vs image because FPGA contains a built in sprite class? If this is the case you are better off using the built in rather than building your own! You learn a lot less this way, but you are almost guaranteed to walkaway with the most efficient end result! Either way good luck, hope I helped!